# Error: object not found - cor.ci

Tags: r, psych

I'm trying to use `cor.ci` to obtain polychoric correlations with significance tests, but it keeps giving me an error message. Here is the code:

```
install.packages("Hmisc")
library(Hmisc)
mydata <- spss.get("S-IAT for R.sav", use.value.labels=TRUE)

install.packages('psych')
library(psych)
poly.example <- cor.ci(mydata(nvar = 10,n = 100)$items,n.iter = 10,poly = TRUE)
poly.example
print(corr.test(poly.example$rho), short=FALSE)
```

Here is the error message it gives:

```
> library(psych)  
> poly.example <- cor.ci(mydata(nvar = 10,n = 100)$items,n.iter = 10,poly = TRUE)  
Error in cor.ci(mydata(nvar = 10, n = 100)$items, n.iter = 10, poly = TRUE) :  
  could not find function "mydata"  
> poly.example  
Error: object 'poly.example' not found  
> print(corr.test(poly.example$rho), short=FALSE) 
Error in is.data.frame(x) : object 'poly.example' not found
```

How can I make it recognize mydata and/or select certain variables from this dataset for the analysis? I got the above code from here:
[Polychoric correlation matrix with significance in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19506180/polychoric-correlation-matrix-with-significance-in-r)

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know anything about these packages, but you are treating `mydata` as a function here and seem to be trying to using it instead of the `sim.poly` function in the linked example. That's probably not what you're meant to be doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several problems.
1) As previously commented upon, you are treating mydata as a function, but you need to treat it as a data.frame.  Thus the call should be

```
 poly.example <- cor.ci(mydata,n.iter = 10,poly = TRUE)
```

If you are trying to just get the first 100 cases and the first 10 variables, then

```
poly.example <- cor.ci(mydata[1:10,1:100],n.iter = 10,poly = TRUE)
```

2) Then, you do not want to run corr.test on the resulting correlation matrix.  corr.test should be run on the data.

```
print(corr.test(mydata[1:10,1:100],short=FALSE)
```

Note that corr.test is testing the Pearson correlation.